# unable to select layer mask and folder button - Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The *Mask* and *Folder* icons are not clickable *(see attached image)*. Layer mask is not working. Can't create folder too. I've checked it is not in quick mask mode.

I have no idea why this is happening. It was working fine until today. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: That's [a bug introduced in the latest Photoshop update](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/bug-report-photoshop-21-1-0-new-layer-and-new-group-buttons-in-the-layers-panel-stay-down-after-clicking)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - exactly why it's best to wait a month or two after a release before upgrading. Thanks for the warning!

Comment: @BillyKerr 2020 came out 5 months ago and for me it was nothing but a bugsfest: I was never able to use it in production. _Every_ new patch adds more bugs. A very dissapointing release. So I'd add "update but never remove a previous version that works for you" :)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - good advice!

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thanks! That bug caused me hours of madness. In that thread, the reported problem seems to be from Win10 users. If any other Mac user who encountered the same problem and chance upon this...to let you know, I am a Mac user, so this issue is not just for Win10.